# Printing elements of dictionary line by line

Tags: python

I have a dictionary in a file and i should write a python code to print the keys and values in seperate lines.(without using .keys() and .values().

For eg: dict={"the":"1", "and":"2"} should return as

```
the:1          
and:2
```

Here is my code i tried. I am new to python dictionary. Please help me fix this.

```
dict2 = {}

f= open("dict.txt", 'r')
    for line in f:
        it = line.split()
        k, v = it[0], it[1:]
        dict2[k] = v
return (dict2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to print the key values out of a dictionary in the same order as they appear in the file using a standard dict that won't work (python dict objects don't maintain order). Assuming you want to print by the value of the dicts values...

```
lines = ["the 1", "and 2"]
d = {}

for l in lines:
    k, v = l.split()
    d[k] = v

for key in sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True):
    print ":".join([key, d[key]])
```

assuming you can use `lambda` and string concatenation.

```
lines = ["the 1", "and 2"]
d = {}

for l in lines:
    k, v = l.split()
    d[k] = v

for key in sorted(d, key=lambda k: d[k], reverse=True):
    print key + ":" + d[key]
```

with out lambda

```
for value, key in sorted([(d[k], k) for k in d], reverse=True):
    print key + ":" + value
```

to make a function out of it

```
def lines_to_dict(lines):
    return_dict = {}
    for line in lines:
        key, value = line.split()
        return_dict[key] = value

    return return_dict

if __name__ == "__main__":

    lines = ["the 1", "and 2"]
    print lines_to_dict(lines)
```

Comment: Hi, i cannot use .join and .get but can use .sorted() and .split(). Is it possible to modify your code?

Comment: Hi, thanks but i cannot use lambda as well. No inbuilt functions to be used other than .split(), .sorted()

Comment: @Pramod, for future reference you should add any solution constraints to your question ahead of time =P.

Comment: Sure john thanks. There is another problem. The program should return a value, not print. Like i should store the new dictionary in another variable and then return it. I tried modifying your code but was not successful since i am new to this area.

Comment: are you sure you want to return a dict, remember a dictionary won't maintain sorted information. If you want to maintain the order of the information you can use a tuple or a list. I would suggest an [ordered dict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) however given that you cannot use lambda, join, or get I doubt you'd be able to use it. If you want to return something from a program you'll have to use a function declaration. (a.k.a the `def` keyword)

Comment: Thanks john. Can you let me know how i can convert it to return a dict (irrespective of the order) using function declaration? It would be helpful for me to learn as well.

Answer (score 2):

`line.split()` splits on whitespace. You probably want `line.split(':')`.

```
>>> "the:1".split()
['the:1']
>>> "the:1".split(':')
['the', '1']
```

Also note that

```
it = line.split(':')
k, v = it[0], it[1:]
```

can be simplified to

```
k, v = line.split(':')
```

edit: Well actually those two do different things, but as `line.split()` should only have 2 elements, `k, v = line.split(':')` will do what you want, whereas `it[1:]` would return `['1']` instead of `'1'`.

Though I guess to more gracefully handle parsing issues you could do:

```
it = line.split()
if len(it) != 2:
    print "Error!"
k, v = it[0], it[1]  # note it[1] and not it[1:]
```

Comment: @Pramod What's not working? It's giving you a runtime error? It's not producing the correct output?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the key/value are both strings, then you can parse the dictionary and extract the elements. Note, since this doesn't actually create the dictionary, duplicate elements and the order is preserved - which you may wish to account for.

```
import ast

text = '{"the":"1", "and":"2"}'
d = ast.parse(text).body[0].value
for k, v in zip(d.keys, d.values):
    print '{}:{}'.format(k.s, v.s)
```