# How to construct nested dictionary comprehension in Python with correct ordering?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, dictionary-comprehension

I was trying to shorten the code for [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446282/printing-elements-of-dictionary-line-by-line) when I encountered the problem.

Basically, I was trying a nested dictionary comprehension & was unsuccessful in the attempt.
Here is what I tried.

```
dict2 = {key:value for key, value in line.split(":")
                   for line in ["1:One", "2:Two", "4:Four"]}
print dict2
```

When I run this, it gives me

```
NameError: name 'line' is not defined
```

And, when I reverse the `for` statements like this

```
dict2 = {key:value for line in ["1:One", "2:Two", "4:Four"]
                   for key, value in line.split(":")}
print dict2
```

It results in

```
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I need help on the nesting structure of `dictionary` (or `list`) comprehension. An example would be help a lot.

Comment: This is actually a superb question and underlines something totally unaddressed in Python doc. There are also many ways to implement this badly. Hopefully this gets documented so we do not become PERL...

Comment: @smci Python is open sourced, you can always submit a patch :) Docs are easier than code since minimal testing is needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that there is a better way of doing this without a dict comprehension; see below. I’ll first address the issues with your approach.

You need to use *nesting order* in comprehensions. List your loops in the same order they would be in when nesting a regular loop.

The `line.split()` expression returns a sequence of two items, but each of those items is *not* a tuple of a key and a value; instead there is only ever *one* element being iterated over. Wrap the split in a tuple so you have a 'sequence' of `(key, value)` items being yielded to assign the two results to two items:

```
dict2 = {key:value for line in ["1:One", "2:Two", "4:Four"]
                   for key, value in (line.split(":"),)}
```

This is the equivalent of:

```
dict2 = {}
for line in ["1:One", "2:Two", "4:Four"]:
    for key, value in (line.split(":"),):
        dict2[key] = value
```

where the nested loop is only needed because you cannot do:

```
dict2 = {}
for line in ["1:One", "2:Two", "4:Four"]:
    key, value = line.split(":")
    dict2[key] = value
```

However, in this case, instead of a dictionary comprehension, you should use the `dict()` constructor. It *wants* two-element sequences, simplifying the whole operation:

```
dict2 = dict(line.split(":") for line in ["1:One", "2:Two", "4:Four"])
```

Comment: I'd prefer to use `dict(el.split(':') for el in the_list)`

Comment: So, only a `tuple` lets us assign values to multiple variables (through unpacking)?!

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil: You have `for key, value in ('key', 'value')` here, that does not work. But `for key, value in (('key', 'value'),)` *does*.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil: The `for` loop is doing tuple unpacking into two variables, so *each iteration* over the sequence on the right-hand side *must* contain two elements. `line.split(':')` creates a sequence with just *one* element.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil: By adding an outer tuple, suddenly you have a sequence that yields two elements on each iteration. There is only one iteration, but `yield` doesn't care.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So, if I have a custom `.split` function that instead returns 2 variables, problem solved?

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil: Only if it returns a *sequence* of 2-value pairs. It could also be an iterator, of course, but each iteration must yield a pair of values.

Comment: The other answer by @iCodez is actually far more elegant than all this tuple-unpacking/repacking Olympics, and should be accepted. The workaround `for key, value in (('key', 'value'),)` is a code smell that you should be using a fn/constructor which directly accepts/iterates over tuples.

Comment: @smci: did you read my *whole* answer? I end my answer with *exactly that technique*. I answered the question and gave the better option.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: then that line needs to go first. With a clear statement that the rest of the answer is suboptimal. iCodez' answer is currently clearer.

Comment: @smci perhaps, but their answer fails to address the issues raised in the question.

Comment: @smci I’ve edited to point out at the top there is a better option.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this a lot simpler with [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#func-dict) and a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
>>> lst = ["1:One", "2:Two", "4:Four"]
>>> dict(x.split(":") for x in lst)
{'4': 'Four', '1': 'One', '2': 'Two'}
>>>
```

Comment: This is actually far more elegant than the accepted answer (tuple-unpacking/repacking Olympics) and should be the accepted answer. cc @MartijnPieters

Comment: @smci But that's not what the question demands. Martijn's answer nicely describes what I am doing wrong, how it's supposed to be done **and** how to efficiently do it without dict comprehension.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil: yes, and I independently came here looking for the same (order/unpacking issue in nested dict comprehension). But comparing the nested-dict-comp approach to using a dict-constructor-taking-tuples-of-(key,value) , we clearly see that a (key,value)-pair-tuple-inside-a-1-tuple to workaround the unpacking/order is a Python antipattern, and one so bad and confusing that users should be warned off using it, very loud and clear. Like I said, if we allow 33 ways of implementing something, and 32 of them suboptimal and unreadable, we will quickly become PERL. Which is to be avoided